# Overcoming lexing ambiguity

Tags: antlr4

**UPDATED 25/10/20**

I have a record oriented file format where `('\r'? '\n' | '\r')` [i.e. NEWLINE] can be the termination of a sequence of characters or, on its own, the separator between two records. Also there is free text in each record.

Two issues I'm having is that:

1. If I include numbers and punctuation within the definition of TEXT then `timestamp` stops recognizing,
2. I would like to handle the newline which separates two records differently to the line termination newline.

I want to parse this simple file format:

```
1
00:00:01,123 --> 00:00:10,000
First caption is here
Second caption is here

2
00:00:10,001 --> 00:00:20,200
Third caption with fourth caption missing
```

My grammar is this:

```
grammar str;

str_file:   record+;

record:     frameLine timestamp caption caption? NEWLINE ;

frameLine:  FRAME_ID NEWLINE ;

timestamp:  TIMECODE ARROW TIMECODE NEWLINE ;

caption:    TEXT NEWLINE;

NEWLINE:    ('\r'? '\n' | '\r') ;

FRAME_ID:   [0-9]+ ;

ARROW:      ' --> ';

TEXT:   ('A'..'Z'
            | 'a'..'z'
            | ' ')+ ;

TIMECODE:   [0-9][0-9] ':' [0-9][0-9] ':' [0-9][0-9] ',' [0-9][0-9][0-9];
```

**UPDATE AFTER REFACTORING**

Bart's answer below is definitely more reliable than my re-factoring below which also seems to work but probably doesn't parse some inputs:

```
grammar Subtitles;

subtitles:   record+ EOF;

record:     frameLine timestamp caption caption? NEWLINE ;

frameLine FRAME_ID NEWLINE ;

timestamp:  TIMECODE ARROW TIMECODE NEWLINE;

caption:    TEXT NEWLINE;

NEWLINE:    ('\r'? '\n' | '\r') ;

FRAME_ID:   [0-9]+ ;

ARROW:      ' --> ';

TIMECODE:   [0-9][0-9] ':' [0-9][0-9] ':' [0-9][0-9] ',' [0-9][0-9][0-9];

TEXT:      (WORD | NUM | ' ' | PUNC)+;

WORD:   [\u0041-\u007a\u00c0-\u00ff]+;

NUM:    ('0'..'9')+;

PUNC:   '/' | '*' | ':' | ', ';
```

Comment: When I add the missing header to your grammar, compile it and run it on an input containing three new lines, I get one `SEPARATOR` token and one `NEWLINE` token. That's the expected result, right? So I think your problem is related to the rest of your grammar, your input, how you read your input or how you invoke the grammar. So you should post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this is that some characters have a different meaning in a certain context: a digit can be a frame ID, part of a timestamp, or part of text. And theoretically, a timestamp like `00:00:10,001` could even be part of a line of text. ANTLR's lexer does not handle such context sensitivity well.

What you could do is leverage [lexer modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes). Assuming the input will always start with a frame ID, then when the lexer "sees" a line break after a frame ID, it moves into the time-mode. In this time mode, you know you'll be matching  timestamps separated with an arrow, and when you "see" a new line in that mode, you'll move to the text-mode. This text-mode will end whenever you "see" 2 successive line breaks.

A quick demo:

#### File: SrtLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar SrtLexer;

FRAME_ID
 : [0-9]+
 ;

NEW_LINE
 : NL -> skip, mode(TIME_MODE)
 ;

fragment NL :  '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
fragment S  : [ \t];
fragment D  : [0-9];

mode TIME_MODE;

  TIME_STAMP
   : D D ':' D D ':' D D ',' D D D
   ;

  ARROW
   : '-->'
   ;

  TIME_MODE_SPACE
   : S -> skip
   ;

  TIME_MODE_NEW_LINE
   : NL -> skip, mode(TEXT_MODE)
   ;

mode TEXT_MODE;

  TEXT_LINE
   : ~[\r\n]+
   ;

  TEXT_MODE_NEW_FRAME
   : NL NL -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
   ;

  TEXT_MODE_NEW_LINE
   : NL -> skip
   ;
```

#### File: SrtParser.g4

```
parser grammar SrtParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=SrtLexer;
}

parse
 : frame+ EOF
 ;

frame
 : FRAME_ID time text
 ;

time
 : TIME_STAMP ARROW TIME_STAMP
 ;

text
 : TEXT_LINE+
 ;
```

If you now parse your example input, you'll end up with the following parse tree:

[image]

Note that this way, input like:

```
1
00:00:01,123 --> 00:00:10,000
And then he typed 00:00:01,123 --> 00:00:10,000
```

will also be parsed correctly.

Comment: what an awesome answer, thanks. I did consider the use of lexer modes but had to go away and read up on them. Interestingly, I did try several bit of re-factoring in my grammar, mostly adding more granular lexer rules for `WORD`, `NUM` and `PUNC`, and what I added to my question works too (although I suspect there are some inputs that it won't parse).

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend using lexer rules within other ones: it makes lexer context free. Use `fragment` rules instead:

```
SEPARATOR : NEWLINE_FRAGMENT NEWLINE_FRAGMENT;
NEWLINE   : NEWLINE_FRAGMENT;
fragment NEWLINE_FRAGMENT: ('\r'? '\n' | '\r');
```

I've encountered only one case where recursive lexer rules are required: recursive comments (for instance, [Slash Star comment](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/tsql/TSqlLexer.g4#L847) in T-SQL), but they are rarely used.

Comment: There's nothing context free about OP's lexer rules - they aren't recursive. And if they were, introducing a fragment with the exact same contents as `NEWLINE` still wouldn't change anything. With your suggested changes, the grammar would be completely equivalent to the original, so whatever issues OP is having with his grammar would still be there.

Comment: ANTLR lexer rules are left recursive, see documentation: [Recursive Lexer Rules](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#recursive-lexer-rules) Actually, ANTLR lexer and parser have the same expressive power.

And these grammars are not equivalent since fragment rules are not real rules.

Comment: Lexer rules *can* be recursive (and so can fragments btw). OP's rules aren't. And introducing a fragment here changes absolutely nothing about the behaviour of the grammar. "fragment rules are not real rules" Sure, but `NEWLINE` is a real rule. And since `NEWLINE` is defined to be the same as `NEWLINE_FRAGMENT`, you still have the exact same set of lexer rules with the exact same behaviour.